# how to get Closure result in Python3

Tags: python, closures

I'm using Python3, I read the book "Python for Data Analysis" and try to run the following code that use *closure*.

```
def make_closure(a):
    def closure():
        print('I know the secret: %d' % a)
    return make_closure

make_closure(5)
```

the result is

```
Out[70]: <function __main__.make_closure>
```

while the book told me that "So in the above case, the returned closure will
always print I know the secret: 5 whenever you call it."

How to get the result as the book? Is that because I use Python 3?

Comment: You need to return `closure` not `make_closure`.

Comment: You will also need to call the returned function.

Comment: @Renke It's fine, no harm done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `closure` rather than `make_closure`. `closure` is the *closure*, and `make_closure` is the function creating the closure:

```
>>> def make_closure(a):
...     def closure():
...         print('I know the secret: %d' % a)
...     return closure
... 
>>> f = make_closure(5)
>>> f()
I know the secret: 5
```

If you're feeling adventures, you can use the `__closure__` attribute to view what is inside of the closure for `f`:

```
>>> f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closure needs to return the inner function, and then it needs to be called, e.g.:

```
>>> def make_closure(a):
...     def closure():
...         print('I know the secret: %d' % a)
...     return closure
...
>>> secret5 = make_closure(5)
>>> secret2 = make_closure(2)
>>> secret5()
'I know the secret: 5'
>>> secret5()
'I know the secret: 5'
>>> secret2()
'I know the secret: 2'
```